# Divide Results Into Three Groups Based On Condition And Date Check

Tags: r

This is one I have been having trouble with for days. I need to take my data and divide results into three groups based on conditions and date check. You can see this in the original data table that I have provided.

[Table with original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoJYS.png)

Basically, I need to do this by individual. If they fail then they have 7 days to pass. If they fail and pass within 7 days then they go in the Yes category. If they fail and then have another failure within 7 days, they go in the No category. If they have a failed result and nothing after that, then they go in the Refused category.

So, I need to test the row after a Fail for a Pass or Fail or Nothing by individual and then check that it is within 7 days.

Individuals such as Sam, since he did not take another test after the second failure, can be in multiple groups at the same time. Luke on the other hand, passed but it was after the 7 day period so they scored a refused. The final table would then look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCRex.png)

I have tried to use if-else statements but I don't know how to check the next row of the same individual and ignore any other rows other than the row that exist, if any, right after Fail per individual.

I don't know if this can be done in R but I appreciate any help I can get on this.
Thank you!

Comment: I posted an answer, but not the entire solution as I don't understand the data fully. Is this one test? How does Heather have 3 passes and 2 fails, and whats the max attempts?

Comment: Hello Tom, thank you for the help. These are different tests but all recorded in the same column. Heather passed one test without needing a retake but failed the other two she took and had to retake them. There is no limit for tests. Some have over 30 and counting while most are around three or four. Thank you again!

Comment: Every test in one column and nothing to differentiate them?

Comment: No, because the test itself is not important, it is the time that they come in to take a test and the result of the test that we want to track.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a complete solution, but my suggestion.

Your dataset:

```
# A tibble: 13 x 4
   name    result time_1     time_2    
   <chr>   <chr>  <date>     <date>    
 1 Joe     Fail   2022-03-01 NA        
 2 Joe     Pass   NA         2022-03-05
 3 Heather Fail   2022-03-21 NA        
 4 Heather Pass   NA         2022-03-26
 5 Heather Pass   NA         2022-03-27
 6 Heather Fail   2022-03-13 NA        
 7 Heather Pass   NA         2022-03-17
 8 Sam     Fail   2022-03-20 NA        
 9 Sam     Fail   2022-03-21 NA        
10 Luke    Fail   2022-03-11 NA        
11 Luke    Pass   NA         2022-03-13
12 Luke    Fail   2022-03-19 NA        
13 Luke    Pass   NA         2022-03-29

library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df_clean <- df %>% 
  arrange(name, result, time_1, time_2) %>% 
  group_by(name, result) %>% 
  mutate(attempt = 1:n()) %>% 
  unite(col = "result", 
        c("result", "attempt"), 
        sep = "_", remove = TRUE) %>% 
  unite(col = "time", 
        c("time_1", "time_2"), 
        sep = "", remove = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(time = time %>% str_remove_all("NA") %>% as.Date()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(key = result, value = time)
```

"Cleaned dataset":

```
    # A tibble: 4 x 6
      name    Fail_1     Fail_2     Pass_1     Pass_2     Pass_3    
      <chr>   <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
    1 Heather 2022-03-13 2022-03-21 2022-03-17 2022-03-26 2022-03-27
    2 Joe     2022-03-01 NA         2022-03-05 NA         NA        
    3 Luke    2022-03-11 2022-03-19 2022-03-13 2022-03-29 NA        
    4 Sam     2022-03-20 2022-03-21 NA         NA         NA      

df_clean %>% 
  mutate(yes = case_when(interval(Fail_1, Pass_1) %>% 
                           as.numeric("days") <= 7  ~ 1, 
                         TRUE ~ 0), 
         refused = case_when(is.Date(Fail_1) & is.na(Pass_1) ~ 1, 
                             TRUE ~ 0))

# A tibble: 4 x 8
  name    Fail_1     Fail_2     Pass_1     Pass_2     Pass_3       yes refused
  <chr>   <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Heather 2022-03-13 2022-03-21 2022-03-17 2022-03-26 2022-03-27     1       0
2 Joe     2022-03-01 NA         2022-03-05 NA         NA             1       0
3 Luke    2022-03-11 2022-03-19 2022-03-13 2022-03-29 NA             1       0
4 Sam     2022-03-20 2022-03-21 NA         NA         NA             0       1
```